# How can I create dynamic routing in Blazor serverside?

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

Im setting up a blazor app and running into issues.

I have one route in a blazor page with @page "/{city}" and another route like @page "/content-route". The {city} route should check if the parameter City is in a list and then only return that page if it matches for example "mysite.com/chicago".

The problem is the /{city} route is catching all routes like /content-route. How can I setup routing like this in blazor?

Comment: It will [it's logical], there's no difference between `/london` and `/content-route` when the router is doing a match in it's routing table.  They are both text strings.  You will either need to change your routing design or write your own router.  consider using: `/london` and `/content/content-route` or  `/city/london` and `/content-route`.

Comment: Yes that is the question. How do you do that?

Answer (score 0):

I followed this official document to test the route parameters in a blazor server application. As you can see the test result, I have a razor component which routing is defined as `/{city}`, it won't influence the current components with routing `/` or `/count`, only the routing value can't be caught by other components then it will go to `/{city}`, for example if I try to visit `localhost:port/hi`, then since I don't have a component with routing `/hi`, it would go to city component.

```
@page "/{city}"
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

<h1>Here is @city!</h1>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string? city { get; set; }

    public string[] cities = new string[] { "chicago", "new york" };

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        if (Array.IndexOf(cities, city) >= 0)
        {
            //do something here
        }
        else
        {
            NavManager.NavigateTo("/fetchdata");
        }
    }

}
```

[The exception](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17497) can be seen here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

While building a custom router is possible, it's only for the experienced programmer and not the faint hearted.

You need to think a little outside the box to solve your problem.  If you don't have `/{city}` defined navigating to `/London` will take you to *Page not Found*.

We can handle that like this.

Define a `PageNotFound.razor` component.  Here's a demo version that gets the *City* from the `Uri` and then checks is one exists.

```cs
@inject NavigationManager NavManager

@if (_hasCity)
{
    <h3>Cities</h3>
    <div class="bg-dark text-white p-2 m-2">
        <pre>City Name : @_city</pre>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <div class="alert alert-danger">There's no page like that here!</div>
}


@code {
    private bool _hasCity;
    private string? _city;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        var route = new Uri(NavManager.Uri);
        if (route.Segments.Length == 2)
        {
            var cityString = route.Segments[1];
            if (_cities.Any(item => item.Equals(cityString, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
                _city = cityString;
                _hasCity = true;
            }
        }
    }

    private List<string> _cities = new() { "London", "Paris", "Lisbon" };
}
```

And then modify `App.razor`

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <PageNotFound />
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. There is no way to do this if you want to navigate to *another page* within your app, since the string will match everything.
2. If the `mysite.com/Chicago` is an external url, then you can use [catchall parameters and then parse the route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#catch-all-route-parameters) to go to the valid site.
3. However, as design, using API style, unconstrained URLs are not useful in Blazor. Rather, use different data types to enforce unique route constraints.
   Some something like @page `"/city/{CityCode:int}"`